# Modify object's css using jquery whilst iterating through array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I modify the css of an object when iterating through an array of objects? Here's my attempt:

```
var buttons = $('#nav li');
for(button in buttons){
    button.css("opacity","1");
}
```

But this gives the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'css'
(anonymous function) 
k jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2
D
```

Comment: `button` is set to the keys of the object or array, not the values -- JS `for-in` is not like PHP `foreach`.

Comment: ahh, that's why! `$(buttons[button]).css("opacity","1");` works, thank you!

Comment: But the answer from undefined is the idiomatic way to iterate through a jQuery collection.

Comment: yeah, will be using that instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to iterate through the collection for setting `css`, jQuery does this for you:

```
$('#nav li').css('opacity','1');
```

You are calling the `.css()` method on all the keys of the jQuery object and not on the actual selected elements, jQuery returns a jQuery-wrapped array of selected elements, if you want to get the actual array of the elements, you can use `.get()` method and If you want to iterate through the collection, you can simply use the `.each()` method:

```
$('#nav li').each(function(index, element) {
   // ...
});
```